# is it possible to find the ETA of a html 5 file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a html5 file upload script on my site.

it works fine with this progressbar script

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
            var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
            var pci = parseInt(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
            //get us our ETA
            //kilobytes or megabytes?
            var pcia = e.loaded / 1024;
            var pcia2 = e.total / 1024;
            if (pcia2 > 1024)
            {
                pcia = pcia / 1024
                pcia2 = pcia2 / 1024;
                progress.style.backgroundPosition = pc + "% 0";
                elapsedtime = startTime + new Date();
                alert(startTime);alert(new Date());
                var eta = ((e.total / e.loaded) * elapsedtime) - elapsedtime;
            progress.innerHTML = pci + "% (" + Math.ceil(pcia * 100)/100 + " MB of " + Math.ceil(pcia2 * 100)/100 + " MB)-(" + eta +" secs. remaining)";
            }
            else
            {
                progress.style.backgroundPosition = pc + "% 0";
            progress.innerHTML = pci + "% (" + Math.ceil(pcia * 100)/100 + " KB of " + Math.ceil(pcia2 * 100)/100 + " KB)-(" + eta +" secs. remaining)";
            }
        }, false);
```

ok, so i have alerted the start time and the time when the progress is called.
But the variable ETA shows as NaN.
How can you achieve something like date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); (from php) in javascript?

Comment: You could extrapolate the average rate of change of `e.loaded` since the beginning of the upload to estimate how long it will take. There is no way to know for sure, though.

Comment: i have seen something like it on a github example, but that was way too complex

Comment: I don't see how it would be too complex. Get the time at the beginning of the upload, then at each `progress` event calculate ETA as `((total / loaded) * elapsed time) - elapsed time`.

Comment: how would i get the time at the beginning of the upload?

Comment: `startTime = new Date()`. And similarly at each progress event.

Comment: could you explain it to me in an answer? thanks

Comment: then what? im not really experienced with javascript

Comment: Then do what I mentioned in my earlier comment. At least give it a shot instead of saying "I can't do it because I'm too new". To make things easier, here's how you would start: `var startTime; xhr.upload.addEventListener("loadStart", function(){startTime = new Date();}, false); //Now attach the progress event handler from your question, and expand the callback to calculate ETA using startTime`

Comment: sorry @Asad i will edit my question to show you what i did.

Comment: @jordanzhninja You're very close, but elapsed time is the **difference** between now and the start time, not the sum.

Comment: im not sure how to work out the difference, would it be elaspedtime = starttime / new Date() ?

Comment: Also, you need to change `new Date()` to `(new Date()).getTime`, so that it's converted to milliseconds that you can then add and subtract.

Comment: @jordanzhninja `var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();` Then you put all that stuff we talked about. Then, inside your function, you change: `var now = (new Date()).getTime(); var elapsedtime = now - startTime;`

Comment: would i use Math.ceil to round that to the nearest second?

Comment: @jordanzhninja The answer (`elapsedTime`) is in milliseconds. That means `eta` is also in milliseconds. To convert to seconds, divide by 1000. You can then use `Math.ceil` to round *up* to the nearest second. If you just want to round to the nearest second, use `Math.round`.

Comment: oh so thats why it said 4000 seconds. :/ thanks for your help @Asad

Comment: @jordanzhninja No problem. Now that you've solved your own problem, you should post the solution as an answer and accept it, so that anyone that comes by later can benefit from it.

Comment: im still having problems with rounding the number but yeah ok i will do that. thanks again @Asad

Comment: @jordanzhninja What sort of problems?

Comment: it said 7.43798392347438 seconds to go

Comment: Did you use `Math.round(eta)`?

Comment: no i used Math.round(elapsedTime) i must be blind

Comment: done its ok fixed it now works fine thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to find the ETA, you must change the code to this.
the changes that are made here are we have 2 new variables, named startTime and now.

place var startTime as soon as the upload starts, and it should be the same syntax as var now.

this script will tell users the percentage complete, kilobytes/megabytes uploaded vs kb/mb in total, and now the ETA of the file upload.

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {

    var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
    var pci = parseInt(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
    //get us our ETA
    //kilobytes or megabytes?
    var pcia = e.loaded / 1024;
    var pcia2 = e.total / 1024;
    if (pcia2 > 1024)
    {
    pcia = pcia / 1024
    pcia2 = pcia2 / 1024;
    var now = (new Date()).getTime(); 
    var elapsedtime = now - startTime;
    elapsedtime = elapsedtime / 1000;
    var eta = ((e.total / e.loaded) * elapsedtime) - elapsedtime;
    eta = Math.round(eta);
    progress.innerHTML = pci + "% (" + Math.ceil(pcia * 100)/100 + " MB of " + Math.ceil(pcia2 * 100)/100 + " MB)-(" + eta +" secs. remaining)";alert(pci); progress(pci, $('#progress'));
        }
        else
        {
        var now = (new Date()).getTime(); 
        var elapsedtime = now - startTime;
        elapsedtime = elapsedtime / 1000;
        var eta = ((e.total / e.loaded) * elapsedtime) - elapsedtime;
        progress.innerHTML = pci + "% (" + Math.ceil(pcia * 100)/100 + " KB of " + Math.ceil(pcia2 * 100)/100 + " KB)-(" + eta +" secs. remaining)"; progress(pci, $('#progress'));
                }
            }, false);
```